# How does the StumbleUpon chrome extension insert a div above the google homepage navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that will insert a horizontal div at the top of all web pages. It works fine for most pages, but for http://google.com, google's navbar is displayed on top of mine. The stumbleUpon chrome extension has a similar feature, except their horizontal div is displayed above google's navbar. I'm using a content script to insert the div. I've tried body.prepend() and it doesn't seem to do the job. 
Also, I would like the bar to be fixed at the top regardless of scroll position. I have it as position:fixed, top:0% but still no luck.
Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with situations like this, be sure to use the computed style box in the webkit inspector. It may take some time to find the right element with the styling that is causing you the issue but it's worth it.

[image]

I prepended a div to the body at http://google.com and applied the following styles:

```
element.style {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I noticed that the red was poking out from behind Google's nav bar so I figured it was probably a z-index issue.

[image]

I set the z-index of my prepended div to 99999 and it showed up as expected. Upon further investigation I found that Google's div #gbx3 has a z-index of 990 and the nav links inside it have a z-index of 991. You don't want to cover up the Google nav bar so we are going to have to set some custom styling on it.

[image]

If you style Google's div #mngb to

```
element.style {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}
```

[image]

This will push Google's nav bar down but doesn't move anything else on the page.

[image]

This should be enough to get you started. It's not perfect and it doesn't handle pushing any of the other content down and it isn't generalized for any other sites but it is a good start for you.

Comment: @Cody, Thanks! Kind of funny that Frankie hasn't accepted it yet but that's the way things go sometimes on SO.